# CSS throwing 503 error with node.js on a2hosting

Tags: css, node.js, express, hosting

I followed this great tutorial on setting up node.js on a2hosting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAD5JyOymRg

everything seems to work except for the CSS does not load in Firefox or Chrome and throws a 503 error for some reason. It also throws a 503 error if I point the `href` to no file at all. I have tried changing the `href` link to `/stylesheets/style.css` or moving style.css around but have not had any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/testapp/static', express.static('public'));

app.get('/testapp', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

app.listen();
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My App",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^6.14.7",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://*mysite*.com/testapp/static/stylesheets/style.css' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello <%=title%></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Here's the folder structure:

```
testapp
-public
--stylesheets
---style.css
-views
--index.ejs
-server.js
-package.json
-node_modules
```

Comment: Does your site reside behind a proxy (like nginx)?

Comment: Not as far as I know, it's with a2hosting and I haven't done anything fancy with it

Comment: Can you share the http response headers from the 503? Was the 503 response body empty? Do you see any messages in your a2hosting error logs accessible from your control panel home page?

Comment: Try using the absolute path as `app.use('/testapp/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` and let us know if this works

Answer (score 2):

1. Please, make sure that your `testapp` is a correct Application URL (**not Application root**)

   [image: ExpressJS configuration panel]
2. Your starting file is called `server.js`, however your package.json refers to `app.js`. Don't you have some *additional* files which may work instead of the one you think? Please, check the Application startup file is correct.
3. If the first options didn't help, check the `.htaccess` file configurations in your `/home/<username>/public_html` directory according to the instructions https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts#Integrating-a-Node.js-application-with-the-web-server

Please let me know if some of the options were helpful or you need some additional information or research.

Comment: Since the html page is working, I think your first to options are not appliable, however the third one could really take place

Comment: You could be right regarding at least the first point. Actually, the second option is also possible IMHO

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to see html and not CSS, try tweaking second parameter where you specify the directory location.

```
app.use('/testapp/static', express.static('public'));
```

The path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process ([link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)).

I had provided a sample code which you could refer where I had put one folder inside the directory and one outside. - https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-grass-0dxvh?file=/testapp/server.js

Answer (score 2):

Change From

```js
app.use('/testapp/static', express.static('public'));
```

to

```js
app.use('/testapp/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

For express serving static files see [link1](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express) & [link2](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static).